# Salesforce how to change the color for pageBlockTable

Tags: salesforce, apex

In VF I'm render a pdf file to print I want a table to show all the product in orderItem. It work however it showing the hyperlink in blue how do I change the color I try everything I could think plug google search for weeks.

Here my code:

```html
<apex:pageBlockTable style="width:100%; margin-top:2%;" value="{!orderItem}" var="product">
    <apex:column  value="{!product.Product2Id}"/>
    <apex:column value="{!product.Case__c}"/>
    <apex:column value="{!product.Each__c}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the default style, you may need to write your custom CSS with `<style>` tag before your pageBlockTable.

For the elements' id or class, use Developer console in your browser.

Your may refer to https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_styling_custom.htm

Answer (score 0):

```css
.pbtb{
     
      background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<apex:pageBlockTable style="background-color:red;" style>
test Record 1<br/>
test Record 2<br/>
test Record 3
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.